# Display links to other colors on Shopify product page

Tags: shopify, shopify-template

I have an online store on Shopify with one product in 10 different colours. So for SEO purposes, I've created 10 products like T-Shirt Black, T-Shirt Blue, T-Shirt Red, etc. To each product, I assigned its own tag and unique description.

What I am trying to do is to link all products between each other from each product page, for instance, the current viewing product is T-Shirt Black, on that page I'd like to show 10 **clickable** colours/swatch with images of each colour and to the current viewing one add the active class, when clicked on another colour it takes user to another product page. How do I make it happen?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: How to make it happen? Messily :P There's plenty of ways to do this, but they're all going to be varying degrees of hacky and will introduce a bunch of overhead in either Liquid logic or AJAX calls during the page load.  Are you sure you can't achieve your desired SEO by using a descriptive schema(eg: JSON-LD, https://json-ld.org/) instead of relying on artificially bloating your page count?  Google does weight links by quality, after all.

Comment: Sorry, my bad I should've also mentioned that ten different colours/products are part of the UX design requested by the client. There are 3 steps to shop, on the home page (step 1) I have 3 Collections when the user selects/clicks one of them he gets ends up begin on another page Available colours (Step 2) at this step user chooses his preferred colour and moves to Product page (Step 3) where he views all the details about selected product. I know it's to install third-party colour swatch apps and pay the monthly fee, but I prefer a solution without using the apps.

Comment: Hmm. Maybe not so messy, then  - It sounds like Step 2 is a collection page, right? So you'll have `collection.products` in Liquid, and as long as that's a reasonable number of products (ie, fits within a reasonable pagination size) you shouldn't have any issues. Would it work to create a custom collection template for your step 2 collections, designing it like a product page where the swatches are the individual products?  (There would be some assumptions that all the products in the collection have the same option dimensions - so all either single-variant ones or having common 'sizes'....)

Comment: Correct! 

Step 1 contains a thre varieties;
Collection 1 - SMALL
Collection 2 - MEDIUM
Collection 3 - LARGE

Step 2 is a collection page that uses a custom template, on this page user sees swatches, ten colours as individual products with same option dimensions (size).

The product URL structure looks like www.example.com/collections/brand-t-shirt-**size/colour**

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to share with other people who might need to solve the same task.

Here's what I've done to get this work;

First, I've added a tag to each product based on its collection, in an example for all products in collection SMALL I've added tag ***small***, then I had to write this code to get a list of all the products with the same tag.

```
  {% if product.tags contains "small" %}
        {% assign current_product_tag = "small" %}
  {% elsif product.tags contains "medium" %}
        {% assign current_product_tag = "medium" %}
  {% elsif product.tags contains "large" %}
        {% assign current_product_tag = "large" %}
  {% endif %}

  {% assign current_product = product %}
    <div id="sw_container">
      <p class="sw_title">Select Colour</p>
      <ul class="sw_list">
  {% for product in collections.all.products %}
  {% if product.tags contains current_product_tag %}
        <li class="sw_item{% if product.handle == current_product.handle %} active{% endif %}">
          <a title="{{ product.title | escape }}" href="{% if product.handle == current_product.handle %}#{% else %}{{ product.url }}{% endif %}">
            <img src="{{ product.images.last  | product_img_url: 'small' }}" alt="{{ product.title | escape }}">
          </a>
        </li>
  {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: I like this approach and it seems like a lot better solution than using an app. I'm looking to do something similar and have a couple questions about your code. How are you handling the styling of the color swatches? I haven't tried your code but it looks like this will list out the color names?